# How to create a straight line and get all the values on the line c#

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I've created a console application which reads Forex Data which contains open,high,low,close prices in an array,I want to create a line touching all the lows(5,14,17) in a data from 5 to 17[image]

I want to make a straight line and get all the values on that line (5,7,8,10,12,14,15,16,17,18). Here the values are the lows of the candles which i plotted on the straight line for understanding.Thank you.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey The values i've are only of x,there are no y values .thats the reason i did not mention slope in my question

Comment: You only need two points to draw a line.  https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html